# How does one become lucid in Copywriting?

Tags: copywriting

I am an Advertising Undergrad and wish to become a copywriter. My writing skills are above average but I can't seem to regularly create the same quality of writings everyday. What should I do to consistently write and create good content?

Comment: You are not a machine. Expect there to be some variance (see also: regression to the mean). Otherwise: (a) make writing a habit, so it is as narural as eating or sleeping to you, but (b) don't exhaust your "writing energy" and give yourself time off to replenish your reservoir (e.f. professional writers often write for only half a day!).

Comment: A large part of writing is also editing, where gaining a fresh perspective is helpful. This fresh perspective can come from an outside eye/ear or from coming back to the work after some distraction (which can include other writing tasks, non-writing tasks associated with writing projects, and entirely unrelated activities such as taking a nap). A fresh perspective helps identify what is wrong generally ("reads like a neon sign" as opposed to "doesn't seem right") and specifically ("telegraphic style and exclusively high-impact words"), which makes correcting the writing easier.

Comment: It may also help that the editing mindset is more analytical whereas the mindset during composition, especially for advertising, tends to be more creative. This difference of perspective may make diagnosis (criticism) easier.

Comment: Re "after some distraction": Author Brandon Sanderson takes *half a year* off his first draft. In the meantime he writes the  first draft to his next novel. Not possible in copywriting, but goes to show how important distancing yourself from your work is.

Answer (score 3):

One good way to answer the question is to cite how I billed for, say, a freelance print ad.  I would quote a blanket fee excluding any hourly rate.  The reason is I may have the headline in five minutes or it may be five days.  Creativity, in short, can't be rushed.

I would encourage you to adopt a process I got many years ago from a Depression-era (I think) book written by James Webb Young, A Technique for Producing Ideas.  Write down any and all words connected to a product or service.  Go to an extreme in this.  For instance, when I wrote copy for bacon, some of the words went beyond the obvious from "fat" and "from pigs" to "red and white," "streaky," "wavy when fried," etc.  What I was doing was feeding my subconscious.

The one thing I added to Webb's idea was to write in one sentence the unique selling proposition of the product.  This can be tricky as some products are no different from others.  I did a campaign for pickles one time, and basically a pickle is a pickle.  The unique proposition, however, was that children influenced the brand their mother bought.  Hence, an animated tv spot and accompanying print drawing on cartoon characters.  A previous campaign had called a pickle a "dilly," which, of course, went on my list of words and from that came "have a [brand name] dilly daily" which is a take off on "dilly dally."  An idea, by the way, are two unrelated things being related as in dilly dally and dilly daily.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is :

> **Be Curious**

The longer answer requires :

- Explaining how being curious matters
- Explaining how to use your curiosity

**Curious Matters Because**:

- If you're going to sell something you must be truly interested in it
- If you're going to talk about something you should know every aspect of it.
- If you're going to sell something that you know every aspect of you
  should definitely believe it is something great and be able to
  explain why.

  **How Do You Use Your Curiosity?**

Research find out everything about your subject
Write Short

Suppose you are selling blogging software.

- Create Blog Entries Fast with editor
- Write Blog entries from your phone.
- Design blog pages with drag and drop controls

Now begin to explain why these are so important with powerful words which are inspired by your belief in the thing you yourself have researched and are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Practice. Consistency comes with practice and keeping conditions relatively the same daily.

In my writing experience, I started out extremely inconsistent. So I made a pattern to follow, where I wrote on paper daily whenever I could and one day a week rewrote everything for as long as it took, often past sunrise the next day. Those were some of my best times writing. Following that pattern helped lead me to writing more consistently.

These days I continue writing consistently by following specific patterns. Listen to the same kind of music whenever writing. Pick specific times of the day to write. Make a cup of coffee or tea before you start. If you set yourself up for writing, the consistency will follow.

Then just keep practicing and the level of consistency will get closer to what you'd expect day to day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean 'articulate', no?
The previous answer is the best - curious and critical reading - continuous reading - of all types of material. Try to work with as great a variety of sentence and phrasal constructions as possible, so the unusual and effective in any given required situation is always at your fingertips.
Good luck! :)